# Как передать String-и в GWT DataGrid?

Tags: gwt, sql, java-ee, java

У меня есть метод, который выводит данные из таблицы. Теперь стоит задача передавать полученные строки в `DataGrid` из фреймворка `Google Web Toolkit`. Как бы это правильно осуществить?

```
  public void getAllGitRecords(){
    try {
        db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(dbAdres);
        db.open("admin", "admin");
        try {
            for (ODocument gitCommitsTable : db.browseClass("GitStorage")) {
                //может быть здесь данные в какой-нибудь контейнер 
                //стоит складывать? Интересует только в какой?      
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.getRecord().getIdentity() + " | ");  
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("sha") + " | "); 
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("comment") + " | "); 
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("date") + " | "); 
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("h") + " | ");
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("m") + " | ");
                System.out.println(gitCommitsTable.field("l") + " | ");
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.out.println("The table GitStorage is empty");
            }
        } finally {
            db.close(); 
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше использовать dataProvider в качестве посредника и загружать String-и в List<String>. Но если все же взаимодействие c ui идет напрямую, то стоит использовать CellTable и заполнить его list-ами же. Однако, стоит отметить, что добавленные в CellTable данные удалить нельзя. По этой причине и стоит применять dataProvider.